# How to catch click on eto ImageViewCell?

Tags: forms, gridview, mouseclick-event, eto

I have a column in my grid that displays a garbage icon.  When clicked I want to catch that click and delete the row.

How do I listen for a click on an ImageViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

```
gridControl.CellClick += Stats_CellClick;

private void Stats_CellClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Column == 3)
     {
         RulesDocAdapter rda = (RulesDocAdapter)e.Item;
         rda.Delete();
         UpdateRulesDoc(Globals.RulesDoc);
     }
}
```